# sqlite with react-native expo app, inserting date as TEXT

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

This should be a simple fix but I'm stuck here. I have a simple page where a user can enter their weight, and it saves to a database. If I do this for only inserting the weight then it works. When I add the insert for the column weightDate and the value of NewestDate then it doesn't work. I made the weightDate column TEXT but I wonder if the issue is that it's not seeing the `newestDate` value in state in order to save it though?

This code, if I remove the insert for weightDate and that value, works fine. It's only the addition of the 2nd value/insert that makes it no longer work.

WHat am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text,  View, Dimensions, Button,KeyboardAvoidingView, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Alert} from 'react-native';
import Icon from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MatIcon from '@expo/vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import NumericInput from 'react-native-numeric-input';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import moment from 'moment';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('testDatabase');

export default class EnterWeight extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weight:'',
      currentDate: new Date(),
      markedDate: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      newestDate: moment(this.currentDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS.SSS")
    };

    db.transaction(function(txn) {
      txn.executeSql(
        "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='userWeight'",
        [],
        function(tx, res) {
          console.log('item:', res.rows.length);
          if (res.rows.length == 0) {

            txn.executeSql(
              'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userWeight(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, weight INT(10), weightDate TEXT',
              []
            );
          }
        }
      );
    });
  }

    toggleWeightModal = () => {
        this.setState({ isWeightModalVisible: !this.state.isWeightModalVisible });
    };

  registerWeight = () => {
    var that = this;
    const { weight } = this.state;
    const { newestDate } = this.state;
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

          db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(
              'INSERT INTO userWeight (weight, weightDate) VALUES (?, ?)',
              [weight, newestDate],
              (tx, results) => {

                 navigate('Dashboard');

              }
            );
          });
  };

    render() {

      const today = this.state.currentDate;
    const day = moment(today).format("dddd");
    const date = moment(today).format("MMMM D, YYYY");
    const newestDate = moment(today).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS.SSS");


        return(

           <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled">
          <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior="padding"
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Enter weight"
              onChangeText={weight => this.setState({ weight })}
              maxLength={10}
              keyboardType="numeric"
              style={{ padding:10 }}
            />
            <Text>{newestDate}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.registerWeight.bind(this)}>
            <Text>Save Entry</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean?